# Option to flag a cell in a column so it can be used to copy certain row data

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have been looking in to adding buttons to a column so I can add specific rows of data to another sheet. It seems like you can't add buttons to cells so I have made my column cells look like buttons through formatting and then added a click function to determine if the row is clicked. This works but I'm starting to think it'll be better if the user selects which rows they want first clicks a single button to the right of the table to take all the rows out and add them to the other sheet.

Looking at radio buttons it seems like they too can't be embedded into a column but linked to a particular cell such that when they are clicked it can trigger data to a cell. They also seem like they can't be de-clicked either.

Is there something that can sit in a cell that when clicked will set it to say 1 ("Add to Sheet") and clicked again will set it to 0 ("Don't add")? Which I can then read in to a function to determine which rows should be added to the other sheet.

Comment: So, you previously want manually 'marking' the rows to be copied and after that pressing a button to do the copy job. Is this a correct understanding? If so, it would be enough to place check boxes on the first column and check the ones placed on the rows to be copied. They can be automatically placed, too, for a range you need (let us say the used range rows). If manually placed, the **must have their top left corner inside of a cell from the row to be copied**. When the code to copy rows runs, it will also uncheck the used check boxes.

Comment: Why don't you stay with the click_event? If row is clicked and the according cell of the helper column is empty VBA code puts a 1 in that helper cell, if row is clicked and according helper cell contains 1 then 1 is removed.

Comment: Hi FaneDuru, I've created an active x checkbox locked to a cell. Is there a way to copy that down for the rows in my table and when new rows are added it adds the new checkbox automatically?

Comment: Hey Ike, I was thinking there might be a nice clean way to do it without the code but I might have to go down that route if I can't get the checkbox way to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to add a column where the user puts in an X (or a blank). You can put an validation rule to that column so that only X is allowed if you want.

Unfortunately there is no Click-Event for a cell so that you can react on a click to toggle the X, best bet is the double-click (`Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick`), so instead of entering the X by keyboard, the user can also double click on the cell:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    If Target.Column = 1 Then   ' Assuming your selection column is [A]
        Target.Value = IIf(Target.Value = "", "X", "")
    End If
End Sub
```

---

If you think that this is too complicated for the user, you can put a control (like a checkbox) in every cell. However, you will either have to create those controls manually one by one or by code. You need to understand that all objects like controls, shapes, images, charts (and so on) are separate objects and they are not linked to a cell. You cannot access a shape with a property like Range("A1").shape, the shapes are only linked to the worksheet.
To force Excel to move a shape when a cell is resized, you need to set the property "Move with cells" so that when rows or columns are resized, the shape stays within the cell. But again, the control is not linked to the cell, Excel just moves its position (left and top property).

---

I am not a big fan of controls on a sheet, and I will not start to discuss the pros and cons of form controls vs ActiveX controls. If I need something like a button, I usually "misuse" a simple shape for that - every shape has a OnClick-method that is called when the shape is clicked.
The following piece of code places a rectangle shape inside a cell that bacically serves to catch the mouse click. I named those shapes "XShape" because they are used to set an X into a cell. The complete shape name contains also the row and column. The routine first checks if a shape with that name already exists - if yes, no new shape is created.

```
Sub AddShape(c As Range)
    Const XShapeName_Prefix = "XShape_"
    Const DeltaX = 2
    Const DeltaY = 1
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet, sh As Shape
    Set ws = c.Worksheet
    Dim shapeName As String
    shapeName = XShapeName_Prefix & c.row & "_" & c.Column
    
    ' Check if shape is already there
    On Error Resume Next
    Set sh = ws.Shapes(shapeName)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If Not sh Is Nothing Then Exit Sub      ' Shape already there
    
    Set sh = ws.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, c.Left + DeltaX, c.Top + DeltaY, c.Width - 2 * DeltaX, c.Height - 2 * DeltaY)
   
    sh.Fill.Visible = msoFalse
    sh.Line.Visible = msoTrue
    sh.Line.Weight = 0.75
    sh.Line.ForeColor.RGB = vbBlack
    sh.Name = shapeName
    sh.OnAction = "XShape_Clicked"
    
End Sub
```

(Hint: If you set the ForeColor to `vbWhite`, the shape is invisible but still catches the mouse click)

As you can see, the `OnAction`-method is set to a subroutine `XShape_Clicked`. You can use the same routine for any number of shapes, the routine figures out which shape was clicked by using `Application.Caller`. It writes an "X" (or blank) into the underlying cell. Just format the cell so that the X is displayed inside the shape.

```
Sub XShape_Clicked()
    
    Dim sh As Shape
    On Error Resume Next
    Set sh = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If sh Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    Dim cell As Range
    Set cell = sh.TopLeftCell
    If cell Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    cell.Value = IIf(UCase(cell.Value) = "X", "", "X")
End Sub
```

Now all you need is a small routine that puts a shape in every row of your data:

```
Sub AddShapesToColumn()
    Dim row As Long, lastRow As Long
    With ActiveSheet  ' Replace this with the sheet you want to use
    
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).row
        For row = 2 To lastRow
            AddShape .Cells(row, "A")
        Next row
    End With
End Sub
```

You can call this routine whenever needed - eg if a new row is created, it will create new shapes only for the new rows.

[image]

Comment: Hi FunThomas, After trialing the click and double click options I started to look at your suggestion above for adding in a custom checkbox which sounds great. I have the code in but on clicking the shape I am getting Cannont run the macro XShape_Clicked. The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros maybe disabled. I dropped all the code above in to the sheet with the data on it and call the AddShapesToColumn to build the checkboxes from a Worksheet_Activate call. Any ideas? Additionally I'd like to read in to a loop whether the row has been checked with x, how would I do this?

Comment: I have fixed the issue with not being able to find the macro by pre-fixng the sheet name to the OnAction - sh.OnAction = ws.CodeName & ".XShape_Clicked" and it really does work great, thanks. If you're able to help point me in the right direction for how to loop through the rows checking for the x that'd be awesome?

Comment: You should put the code into a regular module, not into a sheet module. To get the "X"-ed row, you could use autofilter and copy the visible rows - lots of examples here on SO and elsewhere.

Comment: The data isn't actually a table, it's being generated by a function in A2 to pull in specific data from another sheet. Would it have to be a table to make that work?

Comment: No, you don't need a table to use Autofilter or to loop over your data

Comment: With the data I have a couple of selectable filters which only displays select rows. For example, the data is in rows 2 to 10 initially and then when filtered it is in 2 to 5 say. This means in column E, it leaves the shapes for the rows 6 to 10. Is there any way I can call a function after the function in A2 has updated the data based on the filter so it will remove any excess shapes in E? I also think I'll need to clear them all and re-populate them when I re-click on the sheet.

Comment: Created a function to remove all the shapes on activating the sheet -

`Sub RemoveShapesFromColumn()
    Dim Sh As Shape
    With ActiveSheet
        For Each Sh In .Shapes
           If Not Application.Intersect(Sh.TopLeftCell, .Range("E2:E999")) Is Nothing Then
             Sh.Delete
           End If
        Next Sh
    End With
End Sub`

Comment: Fixed the problem I had with the on sheet filtering. I created a Worksheet_Change and called RemoveShapesFromColumn and then AddShapesToColumn. I initially had some issues with the delete as it was finding dropdowns so I modified that to the following to check for drawing shapes only :  `Sub RemoveShapesFromColumn()
    Dim Sh As Shape
    Dim s As Object
    With ActiveSheet
        For Each s In .DrawingObjects
            If Not Intersect(s.TopLeftCell, .Range("E2:E999")) Is Nothing Then
                s.Delete
            End If
        Next s
    End With
End Sub`

Comment: A2 had no value, only a func but it created a shape: To fix : `Sub AddShapesToColumn()
    Dim row As Long, lastRow As Long
    Dim Sheet As Worksheet
    Set Sheet = ActiveSheet
    Dim rRange As Range
    
    With Sheet
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row
        For row = 2 To lastRow
            Set rRange = .Rows.Range("A" & row)
            If Not rRange Is Nothing Then
                If Not IsTextEmpty(rRange.Value) Then
                    AddShape .Cells(row, "E")
                End If
            End If
        Next row
    End With
End Sub`